# My box need php-soap-5.2.17-1.i386.rpm, who can give a url link

Tags: php, centos

The box runs php-5.2.17-1 and php-soap has not been installed, there are some web sites running there,  and updating PHP is not the first choise for me. The box is Centos 5.6. Could someone give a link?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic* - also, with PHP 5.2, updating *should* be your first choice.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann On the same server, others maybe use spefices for PHP5.2, I don't know. I can not do this. It's too risky.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the **IUS repo** for the php version you are looking for:
https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/Redhat/5/x86_64/

Comment: File "php-soap-5.2.17-1.i386.rpm"  is not there.

Comment: Its there its just a different name php52 whatever